# How can I use scapy & ASN1?

Tags: python, scapy, asn.1

I have to work with scapy to forge packets  by using ASN description files .asn. These latter consist in tags and combinaison of basic types such as BOOL, INTEGER and so on.  However, I can't find anything on the Internet to explain how it works. 
Bassically, how do I specify that I want to use a given file to scapy? Then, how can I create packets that fit what is described in the .asn file?

Many thanks in advance

PS : I'm not a native english speaker, so please appologize for bad english

Comment: no one? if I am not clear enough, please let me know, I'll try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the packets with scapy as defined in [Adding a protocol](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html#). Scapy already support [ASN.1 fields](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html#asn-1) but I don't think it can be autogenerated from the spec file.

As an example here is a packet that should have a string in the ANS1 specification

```
class SimpleASN(Packet):
    name = "simpleasn"
    field_desc = [
        ASN1F_STRING("echo", ""),
    ]
```